# "choose anywhere to go" or "choose to go anywere" Are both phrases grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

May I know if the following sentences are grammatically correct?

1. Mother told me I can choose **to go anywhere** this holiday.
2. Mother told me I can choose **anywhere to go** this holiday.

Are there any rules to where indefinite pronouns be placed in a sentence?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd say the second, though met with in conversation, sounds rather clumsy.

Comment: They're both grammatical, and they can both describe the same event, though their structures are quite different. That's the way English frequently works out -- multiple paths to the same goal.

Answer (score 1):

They should both be correct but they have different meaning.

1. means you have permission to not limit your holiday choices upfront, if you so desire. (Some people say upfront "No flights longer than 4h" or "Vegan hotels only".)
2. means you have permission to actually *choose* out of a limitless number of holiday choices.

Yes, this is beancounting. The result is the same. But hey, this is language class, not pragmatism class. I hope I'm correct. :-)